# Tkinter: How to call a Button from another class method?

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, call

```
class Something:
    def buttons( self ):
        self.button1 = Button( self.main, text = "Add User", command = x )

    def Window( self ):
        self.main    = Tk() 
        self.main.title( "Welcome" )
        self.buttons.button1.grid( row        = 0,
                                   column     = 0,
                                   columnspan = 2,
                                   rowspan    = 2, pady = 5, padx = 5 )
        self.main.mainloop()
```

Here, I want this line of code, starting with **`self.buttons`**, to call the **`.Button()`** via the class-method ( function ) **`.buttons()`**, and display it.

Obviously this code doesn't work, but I was wondering if there was any way/better way to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just call `self.button1.grid(...)` instead of `self.buttons.button1.grid(...)`?

Comment: Because I get this error:

AttributeError: 'Something' object has no attribute 'button1'

Comment: Call `buttons` once, that's where you're creating the button. After that, you can access him by `self.button1`.

Comment: Where would I call buttons? Thanks for the help in advanced, I see where I have gone wrong!

Comment: Anywhere before you want to access the button. Look in Bryan's answer to see actual code.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to call the button from a function outside of the class?

Comment: Yes, just use the object's name. If you created your object like `foo = Something()`, you can access the button by `foo.button1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I understand what you're trying to do, so I'm going to take your question as literally as possible.

Consider this code:

```
def buttons(self):
    self.button1 = Button(self.main, text="Add User", command=x)
```

When you call `self.buttons()`, it's going to create a variable named `self.button1`, *not* `self.buttons.button1`. Thus, if you want to access `self.button1` from within `Window`, you would first need to call the `buttons` function, and then use `self.button1`, like so:

```
def Window(self):
    ...
    self.buttons() 
    self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2,rowspan=2,pady=5,padx=5)
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of my question/code. I really appreciate the help.